# Check if XML node is empty

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

I have a simple XML structure like

```
<main>
<node1><!-- comments --><!-- comments --></node1>
</main>
```

and this can have any number of sub-nodes or values like:

```
    <main>
    <node1><!-- comments --><!-- comments --><p>texttext text</p> 
more text <br/></node1>
    </main>
```

I want to check if the node `<node1>` is empty or not:
*Condition*: the node can still have comments in it and it should be still marked as empty
I'm doing something like:

```
<xsl:if test="string-length(main/node1//text())&gt;0">
```

But it does not work as if there are multiple `<p>` tags, then string-length function will break because of multiple arguments.

Any help to solve this issue is really appreciated.

Comment: Describe more precisely what you are trying to do. Best is an XSLT, XML source and desired result.

Comment: @ThomasW: I want to check if <node1> is empty or not. Condition: it can still have comments inside it. If it has anything other than comment then if condition should fail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`<xsl:template match="main/node1[* | text()[normalize-space()]">` matches those `node1` elements that have at least one element child node or one text child node with content other than whitespace. So the condition `node1[* | text()[normalize-space()]` might be what you are looking for as it ignores comment node (and processing instruction nodes).